# How to implement `assertFail` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

when implementing my own tool modules and funtions, I want to make sure that my function fails on specific input, such as `assertFail (head [])`, but this `assertFail` function seems impossible to be implemented in Haskell, is there any way to hack it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "fail"? A runtime exception? A return value representing an error? A `MonadThrow` call?

Comment: If you just want a quick and dirty escape hatch for debugging your own code, then `error "my error message"` matches any type so can go anywhere. Otherwise @sara is completely right that there are approaches to handle matters more gracefully (like other languages might use try .. catch) if that's what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can use [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1):

```
import Control.Spoon

assertFail x = case spoon x of
    Nothing -> ()
    Just _ -> error "unexpected success"
```

A relevant question: [Is spoon unsafe in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710928/is-spoon-unsafe-in-haskell)

Comment: A much more extensive package specifically for property testing: [`ChasingBottoms`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ChasingBottoms).

Answer (score 0):

One way to *prototype* `assertFail` could be `assertFail = undefined`, because [evaluating it would raise a runtime exception](https://wiki.haskell.org/Undefined). Another would be using [`error`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Error).

If you're building a test framework, a proper design would likely involve total functions (that never raise a runtime error) which return something like `Maybe String` for a possible error message.

If what you need is indeed `assertRaises`, take a look at [`Control.Exception`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html) which likely would help.

Comment: This would be an unconditional failure, akin to Python's `fail` method in the `unittest` module. The user wants something more like `assertRaises(SomeException, some_func, ...)`, which asserts that a particular call will fail.

Comment: Sorry, it's due to wrong naming. In all frameworks I've seen `assertFail` fails unconditionally; `assertRaises` is indeed a very different beast. I've extended my answer a bit.